# jQueries equivalent to YAHOO.util.Event.addListener

Tags: jquery

Does jQuery have an equivalent method to YAHOO.util.Event.addListener ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Check out [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn).  You can do something like

```
$("#elementID").bind("click", function(e) {
    // whatever you want
});
```

or you can call [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn) directly

```
$("#elementID").click(function(e) {
    // whatever you want
});
```